# Save query results in blocks of 1000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I have the query

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from foo.dbo.bar" QUERYOUT "c:\temp\export.csv" -c -t, -T -S'
```

Which exports fine to that file, but is it possible to break it down so that the first 1000 rows go into export.csv then the next 1000 rows go into export2.csv (etc etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/972074/3983442 Would that work for you?

Comment: @Stephen Not really - I don't want to have to run the command 450 times changing the limit each time :D I was hoping I could run one command that would be able to break it down for me!

Comment: Try this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632236/exporting-sql-server-table-to-multiple-part-files

Comment: @Andrew That would probably work, although I actually did what someone else suggested in that thread and do the full export then split it using a tool called CSV File Chunker which seems to have done the trick!

Comment: If you have to do this repeatedly, you might want to look at SSIS.