# MS SQL SERVER TSQL: FILE EXPORT AUTOMATIC SPLIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, t-sql, split

I am trying to do file export from MS SQL SERVER, ABOUT 30 Million rows are generated into CVS file on desktop.  The file size is about 20 G and must be broken down automatically into multiple files.  How can this be achieved automatically via SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this directly in SSMS. You can use either BCP or Split. Please refer this link

[Exporting SQL Server Table to multiple part files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632236/exporting-sql-server-table-to-multiple-part-files)